# Truncating empty tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to do like this:

```
mysql_query("IF(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM`messages`) = 0 {
        ALTER TABLE `messages` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
    }
    IF(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM`chats`) = 0 {
        ALTER TABLE `chats` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
    }
    IF((SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM`messages`) = 0 && (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM`chats`)) {
        ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
    }");
```

but it's incorrect

i need reset A_I in messages if it's empty, reset A_I in chats if it's empty and reset A_I in users if messages and chats is empty

i have autoincrement id and after truncate it will start count from 1

have you some idea?

**i need one query to reset autoincrements in 3 tables using logic that i write**

Comment: You want to remove all the content if there's no content...?!?

Comment: Isnt your table already empty if there is nothing in it?

Comment: i have autoincrement id and after truncate it will start count from 1

Comment: There are other ways to reset the autoincrement than `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ?

Comment: Yep. You could even combine that with a `select` subquery to set it to the current max ID+1. That way you wouldn't even need to check if the table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

By the way, you have a parentheses issue, you should wrap your condition in parentheses.

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM`chats`) = 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you put the if in php:

```
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS count FROM `messages`");

$row1 = mysql_fetch_object($res1);

if ($row1->count == 0) {
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `messages` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
}

$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS count FROM `chats`");

$row2 = mysql_fetch_object($res2);

if ($row2->count == 0) {
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `chats` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
}

if ($row1->count == 0 && $row2->count == 0) {
    mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `users`");
}
```

Comment: i need one query to reset autoincrement

Comment: No, you don't *need* 1 query. You *want* 1 query. Also, you're using obsolete mysql extension. Create a procedure that you'll invoke, which will fire 3 queries.